# How can I add one more squere in this table?

Tags: html, css

I want one more empty squere to appear from the left side of the 'E' square without moving the table's stracture...

thanks to all the helpers!

```css
 table,th,td {
         border: 1px solid black;
         border-collapse: collapse;
     }
     
     th {width: 50px; padding-top: 6px;}
     td {text-align: center;}
```

```html
    <body>

    <table>  
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="4" style="width: 300px; height: 60px; background-color: gold;">  ABC</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
              
    <tbody>
               
    <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>

    </tr>
              
    <tr>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    </tr>

    </table>   

     </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you want something like this, an empty cell before 'E' cell I have added an empty `<td></td>` before it and to maintain table structure as demanded added empty `<th></th>` as well.

```css
 table,th,td {
         border: 1px solid black;
         border-collapse: collapse;
     }
     
     th {width: 50px; padding-top: 6px;}
     td {text-align: center;}
```

```html
    <body>

    <table>  
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="5" style="width: 300px; height: 60px; background-color: gold;">  ABC</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
              
    <tbody>
               
    <tr>
<th></th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>

    </tr>
              
    <tr>
<td></td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    </tr>

    </table>   

     </body>
```

Comment: I need only the lower square without the upper